# Probablity measurment misconception

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Imagine that there are a number of data about student's performance on a test (out of 100). The average grade of 30 tests is 80. So, I want to compute the probability of getting a grade more than 80 for the successive test. I have no difficulty for solving such problem either through poisson distribution or normal distribution. The fallacy here that makes me wonder is that how can I adjust the probability distribution in a way it considers the fact that the grade can't be more than 100. (Because it seems, I won't get the right answer if I take the difference between 80 and 100 as the probability from the distribution).

Comment: There are lots of ways people impose boundaries on normal distributions...typically they count on the probability that the normal would cross the boundary being very low.  Is that the case with your grades?  What sort of standard deviation do you observe?

Comment: You can use whatever distribution you like in whatever problem you like; this is a problem of modeling more than anything. However, usually when a "real" distribution has some intrinsic bound (e.g. a grade cannot be over 100, a temperature cannot be below 0 K, etc.), even when we use an imperfect model which lacks that intrinsic bound, the probability that we get for that bound being violated is extremely small.

Comment: For example, suppose a temperature is modeled as being normally distributed with mean 300 K and standard deviation 10 K. Then the probability of the temperature being negative, internal to the model, is exceedingly small, something like $e^{-900}$. This is so tiny that we generally don't care about it, since the model usually has much more severe flaws than that.

Comment: @Ian So I don't have to care?

Comment: It really just depends on the limitations that you and any collaborators put on your work. But in the real world, a model having a tiny probability to give "meaningless" results is not really a big deal; the bigger concern is what it does with *large* probability.

Comment: We can't tell if it's a problem in your situation or not, you haven't given us very much information.  If $\sigma=4$ then crossing the boundary is a $5\sigma$ event, which I do think you could safely ignore.  But if $\sigma = 20$ then I'd say it's unlikely that your pattern resembles a normal distribution.

Comment: @lulu imagine oil price average in 80's for 26 days is 13.07$, s=1.02 ;

Comment: @lulu assume oil price can be no higher than 20$, (hypothetical gov policy) what is the probability that it will be more than 14?

Comment: Assuming the price is arising from a large enough collection of more or less independent contributions, I'd call that about 1 in 6 based on the normal distribution, and I wouldn't care about the 7+ sigma tail that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I concur with @Ian.  a $7\sigma$ event can safely be neglected.  But surely your test scores don't resemble this.  That would set $\sigma$ around $3$ and I, for one, have never seen test scores anywhere near as tightly grouped as that.

Comment: Just to put it in perspective:  $\sigma=3$ in your situation would mean that about $65\%$ of the grades were in the interval $[77,83]$.  Seems too high a percent, no?  I'd have guessed $\sigma \sim 10$ or so, in which case the boundary would still be pretty live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of useful speculation here, but let's return to your testing example.
Test scores are often assumed to be normal. (Scores are sums of many sub-scores
that may be, roughly-speaking, iid. Also the population of students taking the exam may have normally distributed abilities. For commercial tests, such as GRE and SAT,
test makers sometimes go to considerable trouble to make tests so that
scores will turn out to have close to a normal distribution.)

So let's suppose test scores in your example are distributed 
$Norm(\mu = 80, \sigma = 5).$ The *sample* mean was given as 80. I'm using
that as the *population* mean, and just
arbitrarily picking $\sigma = 5$ as a reasonable population SD for a concrete example.

Then the chance an individual gets more than 100 points is quite small:
the Empirical Rule says that 99.7% (or "almost all") scores are in the
interval $80 \pm 15$. The probability of a score over 100 is tiny:

```
 1 - pnorm(100, 80, 5)
 ## 3.167124e-05
```

Under the assumption that a successor test has the same distribution,
the probability a randomly chosen individual score over 80 is 1/2, and
the probability that the average score of 30 randomly chosen students
exceeds 80 is also 1/2.   The probability that the class average $\bar X$ of 30
students is above, say, 85 is very small, and easy to compute using $SD(\bar X) = 5/\sqrt{30}.$

```
 1 - pnorm(90, 85, 5/sqrt(30))
 ## 2.160232e-08
```

However, from your question, it seems you are trying to *predict* the score
of a randomly chosen student on the *next* exam, given the class *sample* mean
on a current exam. For that you need to assume that the next exam is of
equal difficulty with the current one, that the student is chosen from
the same population as the current class of 30, and to know (or have an
estimate of) the SD of exam scores for both exams in that population.

If that is really your question, then you need to look at such topics
as 'prediction intervals', accounting for *both* the variance of the current $\bar X$
and the  variance of the score of a future randomly chosen student.
There too many speculative steps in that for me to try to give a
numerical example. (The Wikipedia article on 'prediction interval' is. admittedly, a work
in progress, but it finally gets around to a reasonable interval; many
of the other articles from a Google search are for prediction in a
context of regression, and so not directly applicable to your question.)